# R is duplicating large integers when reading in a data frame

Tags: sql, r, type-conversion, precision

I have a database table with a column containing distinct 17 digit numbers. When I ask R to read a section or all of this table into a dataframe it duplicates some of the values 4 or 5 times and drops others. The effect is that a table with say 17 unique values will end up with 6. This is bizarre. It's happening when I read in the data using the RODBC connection or whether I save them to a csv and load them that way.  It's definitely an R problem because I've isolated the issue with fake data:

```
base_num <- "9600000005206"

# Now create a vector of unique numbers in character format
x <- paste0(base_num, seq(5680, 5760, 1))

x

x
[1] "96000000052065680" "96000000052065681" "96000000052065682" 
"96000000052065683" "96000000052065684" "96000000052065685" 
"96000000052065686"
[8] "96000000052065687" "96000000052065688" "96000000052065689" 
"96000000052065690" "96000000052065691" "96000000052065692" 
"96000000052065693"
[15] "96000000052065694" "96000000052065695" "96000000052065696" 
"96000000052065697" "96000000052065698" "96000000052065699" 
"96000000052065700"

# Convert them to numeric
# ta-da! Duplicate values and dropped values
as.numeric(x)

 [1] 96000000052065680 96000000052065680 96000000052065680 
 96000000052065680 96000000052065680 96000000052065680 96000000052065680
 [8] 96000000052065680 96000000052065696 96000000052065696 
 96000000052065696 96000000052065696 96000000052065696 96000000052065696
 [15] 96000000052065696 96000000052065696 96000000052065696 
 96000000052065696 96000000052065696 96000000052065696 96000000052065696
```

This is what's happening when I read from the database or a CSV where I know the column contains unique values. Thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks for highlighting the problem and how to fix it in R. The problem is still that R is completing this transformation while reading in the data. Even if I specify my query as:

```
CAST(longnumber AS VARCHAR(50)) as 'target_column'
```

R *still* treats it as a too-long integer. I have to write:

```
CAST(longnumber AS VARCHAR(50)) + 'S' as 'target_column'
```

in order to get R to read it in as a character field which is all I need. Any ideas?

Comment: If integers are too large, R switches to double.

Comment: Try `all.equal(as.numeric("96000000052065680"
), as.numeric("96000000052065680"
) + 1)`

Comment: What database are you using?  There may be an alternative of reading it using a package based on `DBI` instead of using `RODBC`.

Comment: SAP IQ but I'm loath to muck around with our database package (or write a new one!) - I'll just carry on with the "+ 'S'" solution for the time being. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to use the `odbc` package instead of `RODBC`.  I think it is being more actively maintained.

Comment: I have a new solution for this. As the long digit is basically being treated categorically (as an individual identifier) the trick was to use the 'as.is = TRUE' argument in the sqlQuery function. Counterintuitively this converts the long digit into a character, preserving its unique value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using integer64:

```
library(bit64) 
as.integer64(x)
```

Comment: Check out the following ('old') post: [Problem with long number from character][1]


  [1]: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-long-number-from-character-to-numeric-class-td3297121.html